# Who should walk the Chosson and Kallah to the Chupa?

Tags: minhag, children-parenting, wedding, family-members

At the Chuppah in some weddings I've been to, the father and father-in-law escort the Chosson and the mother and mother-in-law escort the Kallah. In others, the mother and fathers each escort their own children.

What are the reasons behind these two different customs? Is there a specific reason for each? And are there any other customs?

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that the difference is how strict the community is about gender separation in all circumstances.

Comment: A story about Rabbi Yaakov Kaminetzky IIRC. A chosson asked the Rav who should take him under the chuppah. The Rav did not want to answer. The chosson asked how the Rav’s children were married. Rav Yaakov said that he did whatever the parents on the other side wanted. It seems that bein odom lechaveiro takes precedence!

Comment: @ShmuelBrin. At the wedding of the Lubavitcher Rebbe, the previous Rebbe walked his daughter down with his wife, Nechama Dina. When did minhag charade change?

Comment: One reason could be that the shushvinin are not necessarily the parents these days, and if not the parents (or grandparents), it would be a negia problem to have both members of the couple take his arms.

Answer (score 7):

It is interesting to note that the Ramo (in Hilchos Aveilus! [Yore Deah 391:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9732&st=&pgnum=613)) brings the custom that two men take the Choson to the Chupa.

Comment: And IIRC he somewhere mentions _shoshvinos_ walking the _kala_, which would have to mean two women. (The question sought *reasons*. I suppose an early source arguably qualifies.)

Comment: This barely answers the question, I think. You've cited a source, and I guess the "reason" would be to follow an old minhag. But, there's probably more to it. I'm placing a bounty.

Comment: That is why I started off with "It is interesting to note" which indicates it will not satisfy the complete question at hand. The reason I brought the source is because the caption reads " Who should walk the Chosson and Kallah to the Chupa?"